# Excel - compare two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

How to write IF statements in excel to compare two tables value?

for example,if have two tables T1, T2 and each having two fields P,Q and R,S.

T1:

```
P     Q 
-------
1     Yes
2     No
3     No
4     Yes
5     Yes
```

T2:

```
R     S 
--------
5     No
3     Yes
1     Yes
2     No
4     Yes
```

Let us consider the first row values of T1 & T2 we see above is A2 in excel spreadsheet.
I want to write IF statement, If P & R values of A2 are equal then compare Q value of A2 with respect to the S value in T-2, and result P value in X field cell and result compared value in Y cell. Here the challenge is, S is not unique, so we need to use R value to find the S value. 
Result should be like as follows. If either Q or S is "Yes", the output value should be YES. If either Q and S is "No", the output value should be NO.

```
X     Y 
-------
1     Yes
2     No
3     Yes
4     Yes
5     Yes
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't understand how you get that output.  Please check your comparisons again.

Comment: I believe the bit in your question saying `If either Q and S is "No"` should really say `If both Q and S are "No"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**REVISED:**

[image]

If I understand you correctly, is this what you are trying to do:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,G2,$B$2:$B$8,"Yes")+COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$8,G2,$E$2:$E$8,"Yes"),"Yes","No")
```

What I did is to return "Yes" if count "Yes" is over or equal to 1.  But let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: I tried the same thing with same example in spreadsheet, but it didn't result as you shown.

Comment: Can you post the error image to your question?  Also, are you in the US?  The reason I am asking this is some of the OPs they don't use `,`, instead, they have to use `;` as a separator.  Maybe you can try a regular working formula so I know where it went wrong.

Comment: Apologize, I'm getting result. Thanks.

Comment: And I updated my question below, this is my actual requirement.

Comment: Yes, I'm in US location.

Comment: @user3166984, you should revise your question above.  Your post in the answer as question will be removed shortly.

Comment: @user3166984, I just revised my answer with your new conditions.

Comment: I added a revised question and the subject is "Excel compare two table coulmns - Revised"

Comment: @user3166984 - if this answer satisfied your original question as written you should mark it as answered. If you did not write the correct requirements don't allow that to affect correct answer provided by user.

Comment: I updated as you asked. Thanks everyone who answered.